# selecting maximum field of a column using query dsl predicate

Tags: java, spring, predicate, querydsl, predicates

Im new to query dsl.Im using Spring repositories to get the result set.And one case i have to get the maximum of a column and get the fields in to an entity.My predicate code is below.I get error once i run this code.

```
public static  Predicate getMaximum(){
 QUserDetails details = QUserDetails.userDetails;
 return details.id.eq(details.id.max());
 }
```

And this is how i fetch my resultset using spring jpa

```
public UserDetails findByCustomerId(Predicate predicate);
```

### And this is the error i get:

org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property find found for type com.example.entity.UserDetails.Can anyone help me acheive what i want here.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a `QueryDslJpaRepository` which adds implementation for QueryDslPredicateExecutor

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/QueryDslJpaRepository.html

You can see a tutorial here:

http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-eight-adding-functionality-to-a-repository/

Comment: Thank you.But i want it not as a direct query.Thats y i have moved to predicates.Do u know how to acheive the same in queryDsl predicates and spring jpa

Comment: Yeah..I've already did that.And i m getting my result sets the same way.Everything is working except this one

Comment: Try changing the name of the method ti something that doesn't start with find.

Answer (score 0):

From the [QueryDSL email group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/querydsl/jhZ-pmhsA1U), apparently what you have to do to select the max ID is this:

```
from(entity).singleResult(entity.id.max())
```

So it's

```
JPAQuery jpaQuery = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
QEntity qEntity = QEntity.entity;
Long maxId = query.from(qEntity).singleResult(qEntity.id.max());
```